# jQuery Form Upload success but how to get inserted id?

Tags: jquery

I have upload script here: http://www.saaraan.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-with-progressbar-with-jquery-and-php

the author does not help me what I really need so I came here and really need your help:

What I have to edit, when I succesfully uploaded a photo and inserted to mysql Database and get the inserted ID, and redirect to another file: example: myphoto.php?id=1 ??

I tried to edit in file index.php:

```
complete: function(response) { // on complete
                        window.location.href = "photo.php?id=" **HOW TO GET THE ID INSERTED HERE????**;
                    }
```

Thank you in advanced, my english is not good yet, I am new to jQuery too.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to add a reponse to the php-file which contains the id you used. If you echo out the id in your php you could do something like this:

```
complete: function(response) { // on complete
    window.location.href = "photo.php?id="+response
}
```

Comment: Hi Stijn,thanks for your reply.
I tried but it returns to the link: photo.php?id=[object Object]

Comment: I have it,
I should edit it to 

    complete: function(response) { // on complete
        window.location.href = "photo.php?id="+response.responseText
    }

Thank you so much